# List of iPhone Applications that support openURL:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url

Is there a definitive (or otherwise) list of schemes that iPhone Apps support via:

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url
```

Comment: Additionally, SO would not be the ideal place to host such a list. Any suggestions on where, Wikipedia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) appears to be a nice informal wiki of various custom-URL-supporting applications (although it is missing [my own](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules), as well as at least one other application that I know).  There is also [this post](http://applookup.com/2009/11/iphone-apps-with-special-url-shortcuts/).

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://handleopenurl.com/ which contains a comprehensive and searchable database of URL schemes for the iPhone! Much more comprehensive than my own list :)

Answer (score 1):

The biggest Custom URL scheme list available now is at [www.onemillionappschemes.com](http://www.onemillionappschemes.com)

Feel free to contribute your schemes by scanning your iTunes library there :-)