# iphone equivalent to android intents for opening other apps

Tags: iphone

Is there a android intent like functionality available in iphone. Android uses intents to open other applications from the calling app to use functionality already implemented by other apps. i read somewhere that iphone has url schemes but couldnot find more info on this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the following answer, has a link to a wiki with most of the known supporting apps 
[List of iPhone Applications that support openURL:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812810/list-of-iphone-applications-that-support-openurl)

Comment: yeah looks like url scheme is the only way to do this. Also, sharing data between different apps; it can be done through signed key or url scheme only; no equivalent to content providers in android is available on iphone; did anyone figure out a different way of sharing data between apps which can be opened using url schemes like a remote server or pasteboard.

Answer (score 1):

IOS 3.2 and higher has 'DocumentInteraction' http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

One app can provide some data and request another app to view or edit it (based on file format). The iOS takes care of copying the data from one sandbox to the other)
It also works with download links in safari or email attachements.

There is also openURL, but that's more cumbersome.