# FBConnect: How to display standard FB dialog to post a picture and caption?

Tags: ios, facebook, fbconnect

I can post a picture to FaceBook, without any user interaction, this way:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   facebookMessageTextView.text, @"message",
                                   imageToSend, @"source",
                                   nil];

    FBRequest *request = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Now what I would like to do is to display a standard FB dialog, so the user can modify the caption, and possibly decide to post to some other person's wall, or send as a private message.  Such as (from the iPhone Facebook app):

[image]

I don't need the camera button as the image I pass in is not to be replaced.  But I would like the user to be able to select to post to their wall, to another user's wall, change caption and privacy.  How would I do so? And can I also select to send this image as a private message?

UPDATE:  I can send a photo that is already uploaded to a user's album (via the above code), to their friend's timeline, using this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"http://www.bitsonthego.com", @"link",
                                   [fbID objectForKey:@"id"], @"object_attachment",
                                   @"my profile", @"name",
                                   @"description", @"description",
                                   @"name of the post", @"name",
                                   @"caption of my post", @"caption",
                                   facebookMessageTextView.text, @"message",
                                   nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/{friend's id}/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

I still can't seem to use a dialog to specify the friend's in a standard Facebook UI, and it seems I will have to write my own UI to do this.  Or?

Answer (score 0):

Via the Facebook Graph API (the replacement to fbconnect) with `publish_stream` permissions, you are able to only post a photo to a user's wall or user's album.

Also the API does not allow sending of private messages.  I am not aware of any iOS dialogs to assist you in doing this.

However, you might want to look at something called intents as it's called in the Android world, where your app says I want to let the user do this, and then the OS will give the user an option of what program they want to do it in if there are multiple programs.  I found this S/O article on  [iphone equivalent to android intents for opening other apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728595/iphone-equivalent-to-android-intents-for-opening-other-apps).  Maybe there's something in there you can use for iOS.

Comment: I'm actually able to send a picture to a friend's wall as updated in my question.

Comment: Sorry, what I was looking for is a way to access the Facebook "dialogs".  If you look at the Facebook SDK, you'll see xib files that contain these UI elements, yet I can't seem to be able to call them up.

Comment: Are you trying to get at the dialogs that are part of the Facebook app?  Or are these dialogs available using the public API?

Comment: I was hoping to get the public dialogs and that they would look like the Facebook app ones.  However, I know they are different, but they still aren't' cooperating.  For example, I can't post to a "fan page" with them, unless I am the admin of that page.

Comment: Well, there's your problem.  The dialogs in the facebook app are made by Facebook using their own private API and are not available using the public API.